# Recovering from partial upgrade precise to saucy

Tags: xserver, partial-upgrade

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 lts and I had the bad idea to add a saucy repository (saucy main universe) to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. At some point it stopped, because of an error with xserver-common.
Now that I have restarted my computer, I can only see my background image when I log in.

I opened tty1, put the repository line in the sources.list in comment and tried a few commands:

`lsb_release -a` gives me Release 13.10 and `uname -a` precise.

`sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` ran without any problem but it didn't resolve anything.

I also tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade`but there wasn't anything to upgrade or no new release found.

How can I either get back to a stable system with precise or completely upgrade to trusty? Thank you so much.

Requested logs:

- [`/var/log/apt/history.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7644291/)
- [`/var/log/apt/term.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7644231/)

Current state of Xorg/Linux packages:

- [`dpkg --list xserver-* linux-*`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7647515/)

Comment: How about removing the line you added and doing a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` again. You can use nano to edit the file in tty1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't downgrade like this as saucy is newer than precise. It can't find any upgrades to do.

Comment: @Sneetsher, here it is, thank you! (history.log and term.log) http://paste.ubuntu.com/7644291/ http://paste.ubuntu.com/7644231/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of different commands to install the missing packages or to force the upgrade, I realized that my system was a mess and too unstable, being in a state between precise and saucy.

So if you have the same problem, I suggest you what I did: don't bother you with this and simply make a clean reinstallation of your system by upgrading to trusty:

- Burn the iso of the distribution you want to a CD (I chose Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop).
- Don't forget to do a backup of your data and of the installed packages with `sudo dpkg --get-selections > packages_list` in case something goes wrong.
- Boot from your LiveCD and choose `Upgrade from precise to saucy` (t will try to keep all your data, packages, etc.)
- After the upgrade, check the list of your previous installed packages and manually install those you want.
- In trusty you don't have the 32 bit-libraries and `ia32-libs` is deprecated, so in case you want to run 32bit-executables, you might find a solution here:
  http://www.ubuntuask.com/q/answers-64bit-ubuntu-14-04-running-32bit-binaries-454253.html

Answer (score 0):

- In 1st upgrade command, the number of marked package to be replaced was:

  ```
  $ cat history.log | awk 'NR==3 { gsub("Upgrade: ",""); gsub("), ", ")\n"); print }' | wc -l
  1171
  ```

  (line 3 contain the list of all upgrade packages)
- Number of prepared & unpacked packages:

  ```
  $ grep "Preparing to replace " term.txt | wc -l
  1177

  $ grep "Unpacking replacement " term.txt | wc -l
  1177
  ```

  1171 upgrade + 5 failed trials (xserver-common) + 1 reinstall (xserver-common-lts-raring), So all packages pass this step

  (Compare with `history.log`)
- Numbe packages pass setting up step:

  ```
  grep "Setting up " term.txt | wc -l
  1173
  ```

  1171 upgrade + 1 install (python-pbkdf2) + 1 reinstall (xserver-common-lts-raring)

  With only 6 errors: 1 upgrade + 5 failed trials.

  ```
  $ grep "Errors were encountered while processing:" term.txt | wc -l
  6

  $ grep -i "Error " term.txt
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.14.3-3ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
  ```

  This means that the upgrade operation almost completed the only remaining package is `xserver-common`

`xserver-common-lts-raring` description:

> Transitional package for xserver-common
>   This is used for upgrading.

I would suggest the following, but I'm not sure about final upgrade result ( :) never tried something similar):

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-common-lts-raring
sudo apt-get install xserver-common
```

It's the same package, `xserver-common` has higher version.

Comment: Well, I tried reinstalling some `xserver-` packages, but there are many problems, right now my system is really too unstable. I prefer stopping with that and get a clean system by installing Ubuntu 14.04 with a LiveCD. I'm going to backup `etc, opt, usr/local and home` and get the list of all installed packages but in my case, what should I restore? Thanks

Comment: @blueberryme, `/opt` & `/usr/local` no problem but you may need to recompile them (some `/usr/local/lib` libs may not work). `/home` there are questions here about adding old user. `/etc` no, select the ones you need precisely (same applies for `/home/user/.*` hidden files, some old configuration may not work with new app version).

Comment: Perfect, that was just the information I needed. Thanks a lot for your time!